# Show that $A=\bigcap G_{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Given a metric space $(X,d)$ and $A\subset X$, let $G_{A}$ be the set which consists of all the open sets that contain $A$. Show that $A=\bigcap_{B \in G_{A}}B$

It is obvious that $A \subset \bigcap_{B \in G_{A}}B$ however when Im trying to show the other inclusion, I can't proceed. I've tried to use a contradiction argument but I got nowhere. Any hint?

Comment: Consider $ \displaystyle \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left[ \bigcup_{a \in A} \Bbb{B} \! \left( a,\frac{1}{n} \right) \right] $.

Comment: Very clever @BerrickCalebFillmore

Comment: @Math1000: My formula won’t work, for it implies that $ A $ is a $ G_{\delta} $-subset of $ X $, which isn’t always the case.

Comment: Hi Joaquin. It turns out that your statement is true for all $ T_{1} $-spaces, as the only property about metric spaces that I used in my argument is that points are closed.

Comment: @Berrik-Caleb-Fillmore I don't know what is a $ T_1$-space, however thank you very much

Comment: @Joaquin: A $ T_{1} $-space is just a topological space in which all points are closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
X \setminus A = \bigcup_{x \in X \setminus A} \{ x \}.
$$
Therefore, by de Morgan’s Laws,
$$
  A
= X ~ \Bigg\backslash \bigcup_{x \in X \setminus A} \{ x \}
= \bigcap_{x \in X \setminus A} X \setminus \{ x \},
$$
which makes $ A $ an intersection of open subsets of $ X $ because in a metric space, points are closed. It follows immediately that $ A $ is the intersection of *all* open subsets of $ X $ that contain it.

Comment: 1 minute faster than me :)

Comment: @sranthrop: Thanks. :) It took me a while to realize that the solution was actually that simple.